# GAE get info (headers) on an inbound email

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email

I'm using python 2.7 on GAE. When a user makes a request via a browser, I can get 'meta details' such as IP, browser type, request time and the user object, if they are logged in.

I have set up GAE to receive emails. What equivalent kind of 'meta details' can I retrieve from an inbound email and how do I get that information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [InboundEmailMessage](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/receivingmail) class has the most frequently used fields ready for direct access. These are:

- subject
- sender
- to
- cc
- date
- attachments
- original

It also include `original` field that exposes the full meessage as a Python [email.message.Message](http://docs.python.org/library/email.message.html) - this allows you access to all the email headers and potentially lots more.